# AssertWasNotCalled on Action property

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I'm using RhinoMocks and I'd like to assert that an Action that a property refers to is not called, but I don't care about the property itself.

Example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Action DoSomething { get; set; }

    public void TryDoSomething()
    {
        if(DoSomething != null)
            DoSomething();
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestDoSomethingNotCalled()
{
    var myclass = new MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<MyClass>();

    myclass.TryDoSomething();

    myclass.AssertWasNotCalled(m => m.DoSomething());
}
```

This test fails because of the null check on DoSomething. Is there a way to assert that the Action this property refers to is not called, and not the property itself?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looking at `MyClass.TryDoSomething()` code I think there are 2 cases which should be tested:

1. `DoSomething` **is null**: Then you just need to check there is no `NullReferenceException` when `TryDoSomething()` is called. No need to verify whether `DoSomething` Action is called as there is nothing to call.
2. `DoSomething` **is not null**: Then you need to check that `DoSomething` is called when `TryDoSomething()` is called. Your own answer shows a good example how to do this. But of cource you need to Change `Assert.IsFalse()` to `Assert.IsTrue()`.

Comment: I jumped the gun, didn't read your full response. I tried to upvote the question but it won't let me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestDoSomethingCalled()
{
    var myclass = new MyClass();

    bool methodcalled = false;
    myclass.DoSomething = () => { methodcalled = true; };

    myclass.TryDoSomething();

    Assert.IsTrue(methodcalled);
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestDoSomethingNotCalled()
{
    var myclass = new MyClass();

    AssertDoesNotThrow<NullReferenceException>(
        () => { myclass.TryDoSomething(); });
}
```

Comment: This test fails. Have you ever tried to run this test against the code from the question?

Comment: Updated to reflect your answer